# Quite conflicted on advice given to "learn programming" for game development

Tags: education

I have been reading a few sources online that talk about learning programming with the end goal of game development in mind. I have heard many people saying that starting with Unity is the best way to go but others stating that C++ is what you need to get started with in order to be a game developer.

But as far as I'm concerned, this leaves me in quite a dilemma. Am I right in thinking that if I'm not overly fussed about making little indie games at the moment and just want to get stuck in with learning how to program, is C++ the right choice?

I have begun my journey with C++ and I am really enjoying it. I think it is the time further down the line that I am confused about. I am quite unsure on where to turn and what direction to go down to try and do this game development thing.

My end goal isn't necessarily working on an indie game project, I'd much rather aim to work at a gaming company which in my mind is a bit more realistic.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This seems like a forum discussion and not a question. [Take a look in](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) [the Help center](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for what's on-topic for this site.

Comment: Don't sell Unity short. Some AAA game studios use it too (eg. Blizzard for Hearthstone) That said, the right tool to use for learning is the one that lets you iterate quickly and stay motivated to achieve your goals. If you're getting that from C++, power to you!

Comment: Yeah more studios are using Unity it seems. Its just I get this feeling that I'm not really learning how to program when using Unity. 

When learning C++ I feel that the knowledge I learn from it can translate to other languages and possibly land me in a programming job until I get a game development gig.

Answer (score 1):

I'll say this: pick a language that you wish to learn. Learn it. Learning (almost) any language, whether it be C++, Java, C#, etc. will allow you to learn other languages very, very fast. Often times a programmer or game developer should know more than one language, so if you learn one language well, then you will easily be able to understand and quickly learn other languages. So, if you decide to learn with C++, go ahead. After you learn C++, get into C++ game development, and experiment with making a few games. You can then get on to learning other languages, which will make you more open with knowledge (and jobs, potentially!). At this point in time, games made by companies use many languages - C++ is good to learn, but remember that other languages for gamedev are also becoming quite relevant and more used! So, long story short, if you don't have much programming knowledge, I personally would recommend just choosing and learning a language.

I hope this helped a little, best of luck!